# Error on Executing python3

Tags: python, python3

I have executed this command

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

and after this when I start executing the command `python3` I got this error

```
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 587, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 573, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 287, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 263, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 253, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 595, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 538, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 410, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_sysconfigdata.py", line 1, in <module>
    import importlib
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ._constants import TYPE_INVALID
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Could someone help me to resolve this? Please Note that python 3.5 was already there when I was using Ubuntu 16.04 then When I updated the Ubuntu to 18.04 it asked me to keep that. I left as it is.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: @Kulfy 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: You shouldn't have changed Python3's symlink in the first place. This may cause some features to limit, cause some packages to behave abonormally and can even break system quite horribly. I'd recommend you to revert back the action and make Python 3  to point the default Python 3 which is 3.6 in 18.04.3. Moreover, please [edit] your question and include how you installed Python 3.5.

Comment: @Kulfy I have edited the question. Could you please explain to me how to revert the process back.

Comment: Does `python3.6` exists? If yes, run `sudo rm /usr/bin/python3; sudo ln -s python3.6 /usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Python 3.6 does exist but executing this doesn't give any improvment @Kulfy

Answer (score 0):

```
# delete wrong symlink
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3

# install deleted python version
sudo apt install python3.6

# create symlink again
sudo ln -s python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

There is a good chance this will work out.

Please refrain from deleting important binaries in future.